# Even after memeory set to 2048 in Vagrantfile the virtualbox shows 1024 allocated?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have tried creating VM for 3rd time as docker was failing with segmentation fault due to no memory left.

So I destroyed the old vm and  increased the memory to 2048 in vagrant file.

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", mount_options: ["dmode=700,fmode=600"]
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  # config.vm.box_version = "20200901.0.0"
  config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--vram", "2"]
  end

  config.vm.define "swarm-master" do |s|
    s.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap_ansible.sh"
    s.vm.hostname = "swarm-master"
    s.vm.network "public_network", ip: SWARM_MASTER_PUBLIC_IP, auto_config: true, bridge: PUBLIC_NET_BRIDGE
    s.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.100.192.200"
    s.vm.provider "swarm-master" do |sm|
      sm.customize [
        "modifyvm", :id, "--paravirtprovider", "kvm"
      ]
      sm.customize["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "2"]
      sm.customize["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
      sm.customize["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1"]
      sm.customize["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "swarm-master"]
    end

    s.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    ansible-playbook /vagrant/provision.yml
    SHELL

  end
```

but after vagrant up, I see memory allocated is 1024 in virtualbox ! why so ?

[image]

how should I fix this ?
I am using guest os  Xenial which has been doing fine . I dont know why swarm node uses so much memory.

Comment: There is a similar topic in StackOverflow, can you give it a try and see what solution works for you? => [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308149/how-do-i-increase-the-ram-and-set-up-host-only-networking-in-vagrant) I would suggest trying to put the `sm.customize` data in one reference.